# Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined in edit view

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

getting this error while loading editing view:
**"Warning: Missing translation for key: "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"**

After implementing List view i tried to implement Edit view, i'm using ra-data-json-server as my data provider.
after clicking on rows in list view the edit window is displayed for 2 seconds and then flips back to the list view with aforementioned error message.

thorough my research i found out in a stackoverflow comment that it could be due to: **"in fetch. When an options request is triggered prior to a put it provides an empty response and cannot be parsed."**
but it didn't provide any solutions to how should i handle *OPTIONS* if it needs to.

API Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "test",
    "address": "test",
    "profile": "test",
    "isOn": "test",
    "id": 24
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi iomi, Can you possibly include the line that throughs the error, I guess it's something like `response.data.hasOwnProperty('someProp')`, is that correct?

Comment: unfortunately console doesn't provide any error other than this: "Warning: Missing translation for key: "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"
which isn't that much helpful. weirdly all of the network requests response with status 200

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are calling the request and using this response?

Comment: it is called by react-admin interface by Admin component in app.js
App.js: 
` function App() {
  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={appdataProvider}>
      <Resource
        name="exerciseInstructionCategory"
        list={ListGuesser}
        edit={EditGuesser}
        show={ShowGuesser}
      />
</Admin> `